# How to resolve error 0xc0000139

Tags: dll, qt

I'm developing a program on Widows10 with Qt. If I run it from the command line, it exits silently, immediately. When I try to debug it, a dialog box is displayed saying "During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139."

I know this means that Windows failed to load one or more DLLs.

How do I find which DLLs they were?

Ideally, I would prefer not to download any additional utilities beyond what is provided by Windows10 and Qt.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I resolved my problem.

It turned out the the program I was trying to run hadn't been rebuild since my last set of changes. I'm unsure why that was so, clearly my own error but I'm not sure what, precisely.

For the benefit of anyone coming here trying to find an answer to the question at the top of the page, if you have cygwin or another Unix-alike on your system, `ldd` is a good program with which to start looking through the sharable images you link to.